# Making tfp.optimizer.differential_evolution_minimize to work in parallel

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization, parallel-processing, gpu

I'm currently trying to learn several NNs with differencial evolution method.
I have several virtual CPU's and GPU's.
How can I make tfp.optimizer.differential_evolution_minimize function to use all aviliable computational resources (or at least all of CPU or GPU)?